# Java PreparedStatement: Binding Parameter to HASHBYTES

Tags: java, sql, web-services, rest, hashbytes

Right now, I have the prepared statement below, which works:

```
SELECT email, password
FROM Professor 
WHERE email = ? AND password = HASHBYTES('SHA1','" + password + "') 

p.setString(1, email);
```

But when I try to parameterize the value to be encrypted by *HASHBYTES* (in this case, the variable *'password'*), there is some kind of reading/type/conversion error that does not return results. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
SELECT email, password
FROM Professor 
WHERE email = ? AND password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', ?) 

p.setString(1, email);
p.setString(2, password);
```

I get no error message at all; the resultset returns "-3" in the rowCount property. I'm using **SQL Server**.

Passing the *'password'* placeholder like this: *'?'* doesnt work either. What would be the correct way to parameterize this query?

Comment: What error message, if any, are you getting?  What SQL server are you talking to?  (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?)

Comment: No error message at all. The resultset returns "-3" in the rowCount property, if that helps. I'm using SQL Server.

I'll add this information to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the information you all pointed out and researching about how to convert types in SQL Server, I've came to the following code:

```
select email, password
  from Professor
 where email = ?
   and password = hashbytes('sha1', convert(varchar, ?))
```

Please, verify if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [SQL Server sha1 value in prepared statement gives a different value than hardcoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846256/sql-server-sha1-value-in-prepared-statement-gives-a-different-value-than-hardcod)

p.s
answer in this way, because I can not text comment yet.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It seems that the difference between VARCHAR and NVARCHAR SQL Types might be the key to the answer. 

However, I tried changing the variable type in many ways (setNString, Types.NVARCHAR) and even tried to change the query to

`WHERE email = ? AND password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', N?) `, but no success. Can you help me formulating the necessary changes?